# Gerund or infinitive and WHY

Tags: sentence, gerunds, infinitives, syntactic-analysis

WHY is this sentence incorrect?

"All that they can do is preparing as much as they can."

I know it should be

"All they can do is (to) prepare as much as they can."

But, for the life of me I can't figure out why.

Comment: Would you write "They can preparing°?

Comment: The reason is that in reversible specifying constructions like this, if the subject noun phrase contains "do" or "did" in a relative clause, the complement is restricted to an infinitival, either bare or with _to_. Compare "All they were doing was preparing as much as they could"

Comment: Note, however, that if it is reversed, the gerund is OK and the infinitive is awkward. I think this has to do with gerunds being more comfortable as subjects than infinitives are.

Comment: @JohnLawler But "To err is human...", I feel sure you would agree.

Comment: Of course. Complementizer choice is a morass of details and exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

'Prepare' is grammatically parallel to 'do' and should have the same form. (They can prepare as much as they can.) 
If for instance you wrote : What they like doing is... then it would be the -ing form; what they like *doing* is *preparing*...